# Sidebar background image is not showing up?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image, sidebar

So I only want to change a small part of my website. I thought it would be easy, but somehow it doesn't change and I don't know why. I'm using bootstrap so that might make it a little bit difficult. I want to change my sidebar from just one solid color to an image. And it just doesn't show, when I delete the color it just shows nothing. I'm trying to use the 'background-image' property.

```
  <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="css/flat2.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

  <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper" >
      <div class="sidebar-heading"> <img src="text\flat.png" class="title" alt="FLAT"> </div>
      <div class="list-group list-group-flush zijkantje">
        <a href="index.html"> <img src="text/home.png" onMouseOver="this.src='text/home2.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='text/home.png'" alt="Home" class="glassescase" id="thuis"></a>
        <a href="risoprints.html"> <img src="text/risoprints.png" onMouseOver="this.src='text/risoprints2.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='text/risoprints.png'" alt="Risoprints" class="glassescase" id="glassescase"></a>
        <a href="paintings.html"> <img src="text/paintings.png" onMouseOver="this.src='text/paintings2.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='text/paintings.png'" alt="Paintings" class="glassescase" id="littlehouse"></a>
        <a href="tiles.html"> <img src="text/tiles2.png" onMouseOver="this.src='text/tiles.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='text/tiles2.png'" alt="Tiles" class="glassescase" id="ceramic"></a>
        <a href="alphabet.html">  <img src="text/alphabet.png" onMouseOver="this.src='text/alphabet2.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='text/alphabet.png'" alt="Alphabet patterns" class="glassescase" id="green"></a>
        <a href="collage.html"><img src="text/collage.png" onMouseOver="this.src='text/collage2.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='text/collage.png'" alt="Collage" class="glassescase" id="collage"></a>
        <a href="tarotdeck.html"><img src="text/Tarotdeck.png" onMouseOver="this.src='text/tarotdeck2.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='text/Tarotdeck.png'" alt="Tarot deck" class="glassescase" id="tarot"></a>
        <a href="digital.html"><img src="text/digital.png" onMouseOver="this.src='text/digital2.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='text/digital.png'" alt="Digital" class="glassescase" id="digital"></a>

      </div>
    </div>
```

This is for a larger screen, this is the css:
Navbar2 is for the smaller screen.

```
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: 0;
    width:150px;
    background-image: url("sidebar.png") !important;
  }

  #page-content-wrapper {
    min-width: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: -15rem;
  }

  .navbar2 {
    display: none;
  }

  .zijkantje {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items:flex-start;
    margin-top:10px;
    justify-content:space-around;
    margin-left: 27px;

}
```

Hopefully this is enough code to figure out what goes wrong. I always find it more difficult to change a small detail from an already finished site hah. I'm new to coding btw, be kind :)

Comment: Are you confident that the URL is correct / loading?  That background URL would require the image is in the same folder as the stylesheet.  Also, you should be able to use your browser's developer tools network panel to see if the image is loading properly, or if it has a 404 or similar issue.  Lastly, please see how to create an [mcve]....

Answer (score 0):

U can use the Inspector integrated on your browser to review the code, anyway:

- Are u sure is the correct image route which you want to use ?.
- Set the background-repeat and background-position properties to be sure the image shows correctly, and also background-size if necessary.
- Check if sidenav have the background-blend-mode property, and removeit.